# <picture> element, how to figure what source has been effectively loaded by the browser using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

A  element allow to set many possible source for an img element depending on various conditions (screen size, retina etc...); How to figure using javascript what source has been effectively loaded by the browser ?

Same question when using the new srcset and sizes attributes within an  element

Thanks

Comment: What does "effectively loaded" mean?

Comment: The currentSrc property was exactly what I wa looking for, Thanks